# Trigger build in parent repository from submodule in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have all my git repos and build definitions stores on Azure DevOps. As of now, I have build policies for the `master` branch in each seperate repository that ensures that no breaking changes can be merged into master.

One of the repos is used as a submodule in another repo. Say I have `repo-A` and `repo-B`, where `repo-B` is a submodule in `repo-A`:

```
├── repo-A
│   ├── repo-B
```

When a PR is requested in `repo-B` from `feature-branch` I would like to run my builds in `repo-A` with `feature-branch` checked out in `repo-B`. Can this be done in Azure DevOps and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trigger build in parent repository from submodule in Azure DevOps

I am afraid there is no such way we could trigger build in parent repository but PR from sub-module. At the moment, we could only trigger and build on a single git repository.

There is a [closed user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31866004-trigger-build-on-successful-pull-request-on-git-su) about this request for Azure DevOps. If it is important to you, you can open a new ticket here:

[image]

You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.